# Change the location of appcompat ActionMode toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-actionmode

The appcompat library provides a way for us to move the `Toolbar` (previously `ActionBar`) to any place of the screen.

However, the `ActionMode` (contextual menu) toolbar seems to stay at the top, even though I moved the `Toolbar` to another location.

Is there any way to move the `ActionMode` toolbar to another place, e.g. to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?